# 3rd party controls for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What would be a good 3rd party control package for ASP.NET, easy to use without compromising full functionality? What I noticed from some research is Telrik and DevExpress being fairly popular. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have specific controls in mind that you need?

Comment: What kind of functionality do you need?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a combobox with more serverside events and functionality then the standard dropdownlist and ajax combobox. Also a nice treeview or menu control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Telerik extensively for business/data web apps and would recommend them.

The RadGrid control is a vast improvement on the standard ASP.NET Grid and you can develop data-driven sites with neat UIs very rapidly.

If your focus is RAD and neat UIs with minimal coding, then I'd say go for Telerik.

Comment: Regarding the Menu and Treeview, these are both very versatile and the flexible use of DataSources for both makes maintaining a menu very easy. You can use XML, database or of course just hard-code in markup!

Comment: Out of curiousity if I were to have around 40 telrik combobox's on a page, would it render quickly on postback?

Comment: It depends on what features of the ComboBox you had enabled and were making use of - there's quite a lot of AJAXy stuff you can do that would definitely slow it down when it got to 40 times over. If you had basic comboboxes (without using any of the AutoSuggest style features) then it wouldn't be noticable.

Comment: That sounds good. I tried that with the Ajax ComboBox's and it was horribly slow.

Comment: Well... I dynamically created 40 rad_combobox's with autopostback and it takes about 3-4 seconds to select an item. I have to re-create controls on postback too. If I statically place 40 on a page then it is pretty quick but thats not what we are looking for.

Comment: Have you considered utilizing the load on demand capability of the combobox? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx It should greatly speed up the loading time when having many items in the comboboxes. Their number should not be that significant.

Comment: The issue with dynamically creating the controls applies to any server-side control that you attempt to dynamically add to the page. There shouldn't be a difference between adding them during run-time and having then added declaratively (once the page has been loaded) though. How are you adding the items? Also, when selecting an item are you referring to opening the RadComboBox? If that's the case the above comment should help.

Answer (score 1):

I can say that in my opinion stay clear of Infragistics.

It has been our experience that their documentation is absolutely terrible. The controls are bug-ridden so be ready for the patches. Their support is slow and ineffective; and it seems like management really does not concern themselves with customers opinions; but would rather preach to you about why you, the customer are incorrect, and why they are so right.

I am concerned with the comments here about Telerik's documnetation being incomplete.

I also am also concerned about the concentration on certain controls rather than the cmany/suite as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Telerik too.. very easy to use and lots of functionality. Try their demos.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik is what i'd recommend too.

Using it in enterprise domain and in addition to quality of the components, their support is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik is the way to go. The documentation isn't always complete but there is a huge community around these controls, which is very helpful.

Comment: @Inu @Bex @Lexicon @Widor, I guess its seems to be unanimous. Thanks, I'll give Telrik a try.